# Is there a limit to the number of triggers you should set up in GAS?

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a spreadsheet document that is acting as a contract template for my company and we are using a lot of GAS to make it interactive and to automatically populate other databases. The document will be copied many, many times - ultimately we are likely to end up with at least 3,000 copies of this document, possibly more!!

Attached to the doc is a form and I am considering setting up a trigger via a function so that a notification email is sent to the document owner when the form has been completed. The function to create the trigger would look as follows:

```
function createTrigger(){
var trigger =ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendFormMessage").forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

And the email function:

```
 function sendFormMessage() {
 var emailAddress = "d****@***.com";
 var subject = "Form has been submitted";
 var message = "The hotel has submitted the form";
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 }
```

My question is, each time this form is copied a new trigger will be completed and so when I look under 'All your triggers' there will be thousands of triggers set up! Does this have any negative side affects in terms of performance etc? And is there any other conceivable way to set this up?

Comment: The script is bound to the spreadsheet and everyone makes a copy of the spreadsheet? If so, then the trigger will install under that persons account for their copy of the spreadsheet - it would not show up on your accounts triggers

Comment: Pretty sure they'd have to enable the trigger themselves as well.

Comment: hmmm no not quite that simple. The spreadsheet is auto-generated from another doc. So we auto-generate thousands of these things and then users access them via a link. You are right that the user has to run the script to enable the trigger but I'm going to build the createTrigger function into another function so that this will happen for them at the same point as performing a different function. But ultimately yes, because the forms are autocreated and the owner is therefore the same, each trigger shows under 'All your triggers'

Comment: ahh. I think I answered your question below. I didn't consider they  were autocreated, I only tested if they were copied from a template doc by a user as needed. If I didn't answer your question with my answer, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a templated document, if you're using a bound script, the user will need to activate the trigger themselves when they make the copy. So you'll essentially have to ask them to  The triggers don't automatically transfer. I just tried a quick setup with some office colleagues to double check.

Now, I set up a custom menu item and put it under `function onOpen()` and the custom menu showed up. The user then had to allow the script to happen and okay the permissions, and then I used the trigger builder to set up the trigger for the user in a custom menu function. So that could just be stuck in the `onOpen` function.

If you didn't want the users to have to allow permissions everytime they made a copy, you could set it up as a [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) and have everyone run the function as the creator, but then you'd need to look at the quotas documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas.